# How to programmatically access the 'netsh' API via Windows SDK

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking, netsh

Is there a way to access the `netsh` API (e.g. WIN32 API, WDK)?
For example, I'm trying to get mobile broadband information via `netsh` with the following command:

```
netsh mbn show interfaces
```

So I guess the real question is: what's the actual programmatic representation of `netsh mbn show interfaces` using Windows SDK methods?

An example in **pseudo code**:

```
MBN_DEVICE mbn;
GetMbnDev(&mbn);
char* Name = mbn.Name;
char* IMEI = mbn.IMEI;
char* DeviceId = mbn.DevId;
float signal = mbn.Signal;
```

What APIs (Win32/.Net/.Core) would I have to call to get the same result in a *data structure* like with the command above?

Comment: Yes there is a way to use the same API's as `netsh`.

Comment: `netsh.exe` is an executable, and doesn't provide a direct c++ API. You can probably use a pipe to interact with the executable from a c++ program. The more usual way is to access the winsocks API directly (or through some abstraction like `boost::asio`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In this instance netsh.exe actually exports C functions and these functions are called by NAPMONTR.DLL

Comment: [Windows API Index: Networking and Internet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516.aspx#networking_and_internet)

Comment: Thanks, @theB very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Microsoft tools use internal/undocumented APIs to perform their work so cloning them often require a bit of investigation.

The first step is to download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and take a look at the functions netsh imports. In this case it does not look like it imports a lot of network related stuff (on my Windows 8 machine) but it does import `CoCreateInstance` and `GetProcAddress` so you can set a breakpoint on both in your debugger, this should allow you to determine the functions/interfaces it ultimately ends up calling.

Even before you get that far you can simply Google "Mobile Broadband API", it should lead you to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323268(v=vs.85).aspx). You should take a look at those interfaces and see if they provide the information you are after...

Comment: Setting a breakpoint on `CoCreateInstance` is next to useless. Sure, it'll return an interface pointer. To *some* interface. And then moves on to invoke *some* unknown methods, identified by indexes into the v-table only.

Comment: The first thing it has to invoke is `IUnknown::QueryInterface`, and you know where that is in the vtable (because otherwise COM wouldn't work), so you can at least figure out whether it's using documented COM interfaces (or interfaces for which there is marshalling information, at least).

Comment: @IInspectable It is certainly not useless, you can find the CLSID from the first parameter. If you are lucky the debugger knows this CLSID and if not you can try to look for it in the registry or the internet. If that does not help you can follow whatever it does with the returned interface. In the initial investigation you are just trying to figure out if it is using documented stuff.

Comment: That assumes that the CLSID is indeed registered. With registration-free COM this often times is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right on this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d810752-f647-41f6-9299-27b6adddd536/how-to-get-the-signal-strength-from-a-mobile-broadband-network-adapter-in-windows-7-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

- Add a **mbnapi_uuid.lib** to your C++ project (Linker->Input->Additional
  Dependencies).
- Add a reference to COM Tab for C# project: 'Definition: UCM Extension
  API for MBN Type Library'